# Open file at absolute location in Clojure

Tags: file-io, clojure

I have a file at `C:/tasklists.xml`.

What would be a function that returns the text of this file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use `slurp` [(ClojureDocs)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp):

```
(slurp "C:\\tasklists.xml")
;; => returns string with contents of file
```

Comment: fyi: the opposite of slurp is spit